# Laravel 5.1 Applying Eloquent Relationships to Models Throws Class Not Found in Tinker

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm following the Laravel 5.x Laracast video series and right now it is about setting up Eloquent relationships, which I've got written exactly the same except for the classes involved, but I keep getting a "Class App\Vehicles Not Found" error when I attempt to test this in tinker.  It is correct there is no Vehicles model, but that due to models being singular, so I'm not sure why the error is being thrown.  I've run composer dump-autoload so it isn't that a file isn't being seen.

User Model

```
/**
 * A user can have many vehicles.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function vehicles() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Vehicle');
}
```

Vehicle Model

```
/**
 * A vehicle is owned by a user
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

The database migration and seed were successful, and I've verified the database records are present from the seed.

Tinker

```
$user = App\User::first(); // provides the proper user with id = 1
$vehicle = App\Vehicle::first(); // provides the proper vehicle with user_id of 1
```

But

```
$user->vehicles->toArray(); // Throws the "Class App\Vehicles Not Found error"
```

I've watched the video 3 times to try and catch any issues, other than the model being named Vehicle instead of Article there isn't any difference.

**UPDATE**

With help the first issue was resolved, but calling:

```
App\Vehicle::first()->owner->toArray();
```

on the belongsTo relationship throws an error saying:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Call to a member function toArray() on null
```

Comment: Did you happen to accidentally write `return $this->hasMany('App\Vehicles');` in plural at first, without then reloading Tinker? That's about the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Hi @JoelHinz, that would do it.  I didn't know you had to restart Tinker.  I just assumed it had a watch implemented.  Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Been there, done that... way too many times. :) Glad it worked for you.

Comment: @JoelHinz do you know why the belongsTo relationship for vehicles would be null?  The first part App\Vehicle::first() works, but the model relationship for owner returns null causing the toArray() to fail.  I checked the relationship, migration, and the database for records.

Comment: Might be that since you don't call the method `user` but rather `owner`, you need to specify the table and/or keys. Not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me and eventually [garethdaine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1058154/gareth-daine) a while to figure this out by trial and error only to find out that there was actually a passage on this in the documentation haha. Here goes:

The `owner` relationship is not able to find any corresponding users because it is looking for the wrong column.

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id. However, if the foreign key on the Phone model is not user_id, you may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the belongsTo method:

```
/**
 * Get the user that owns the phone.
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'foreign_key');
}
```

In your case, it is looking for `owner_id` rather than `user_id`. So either, rename the method to `user` or specify the `'foreign_key'` parameter as per the example.

You can view the relationship model by typing `dd(App\Vehicle::first()->owner)` which contains the foreign_key property set by Eloquent.

Also, consider looking into [eager](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) or [lazy loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) to solve the n+1 problem.

Comment: My pleasure. Note that this behavior is specific to belongsTo. All the other relationships do infact use the model name to automatically determine the tables and columns. Your confusion is more than understandable. Why they opted for this approach is a mystery to me but yeah.. Luckily we have the option to override and awesome documentation!

Answer (score 0):

First get the vehicle object then call owner model, like this

```
$vehicle = App\Vehicle::first();
$vehicle->owner->toArray();
```